# why do I get egg_info error?

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, pip, mitmproxy

i am trying to install mitmproxy via pip on ubuntu 13.04 but each time i face with this error: "command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in temp/pip-build-lubuntu/cryptography storing complete log in/home/lubuntu/.pip/pip.log"
i have installed python-pip,  python-dev, libxml2-dev, libxslt1 and libssl-dev via apt-get. my pip version is 1.3.1 and python is 2.7.I checked all related answers for this error but no one was helpful. I really appreciate your guide and help in advance.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be enough information here to figure out what's going on - can you please add the relevant parts of the pip install log from the file path in your question.

Answer (score 4):

I was just facing this issue and found I was missing a couple of dependencies for the cryptography package:

> For Debian and Ubuntu, the following command will ensure that the
>   required dependencies are installed:
>
> $ sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev
>   python-dev
>
> For Fedora and RHEL-derivatives, the following command will ensure
>   that the required dependencies are installed:
>
> $ sudo yum install gcc libffi-devel python-devel openssl-devel

(From: https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation/#building-cryptography-on-linux)

I'm installing on a minimal CentOS6.5 VM and found that I also needed:

libxml2-devel and libxslt-devel

Once done, pip install mitmproxy worked. Hope that helps!